# ArrayList string loop mess up strings

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I've got an ArrayList called PhotoArrayList. It contains strings like "picture1.jpg, picture2.png, picture3.gif etc." There is like 50 or 60 strings in this ArrayList. I need to add path of their folder in the beginning like "mnt/sdcard0/Pictures/picture1.jpg etc." So, I'm using following code

```
Integer PhotoFileAmount = PhotoArray.length; //PhotoArray and PhotoArrayList are same
for(int i=0; i < PhotoFileAmount; i++){
           String PhotoFileAndPath = (PhotoFolder + '/' + PhotoArrayList.get(i));
           PhotoArrayList.remove(PhotoArrayList.get(i));
           PhotoArrayList.add(PhotoFileAndPath);
       }
```

But I'm getting a strange result. The beginning of PhotoArrayList is unchanged while it's middle part is okay and last part gets the path twitce. Like "picture1.jpg, mnt/sdcard0/Pictures/picture2.png, mnt/sdcard0/Pictures/mnt/sdcard0/Pictures/picture3.gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change elements of a `ArrayList`, use the [`set`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29) method to assign a new value to the element at a given position:

```
int PhotoFileAmount = PhotoArray.length; // use int here to avoid unnecessary boxing / unboxing

for(int i=0; i < PhotoFileAmount; i++){
    String PhotoFileAndPath = (PhotoFolder + '/' + PhotoArrayList.get(i));
    PhotoArrayList.set(i, PhotoFileAndPath);
}
```

If you use `remove` and `add` you not only change the indices of the elements in the list; even if you make it work it's very inefficient, since **all** remaining elements in the list have to be moved every time `remove` is called.

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList.add(E Object)` adds the `Object` at the at the end of the list.
You are currently removing an item from where ever it is in the list, then adding a new version at the end of the list. As `i` approaches `PhotoFileAmount` your `.get(i)` statement is going to start retrieving the revised objects that you have added at the end.